# Why mvn downloads a lot of dependencies, given an artifact, but the mvnrepository.com says there is no dependency?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, mvn-repo

This artifiact [AWS SDK For Java Bundle » 1.11.901](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.901) says there is no "Compile Dependencies" (or "Provided Dependencies"/"Runtime Dependencies").

But when executing this command:

```
./mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.901 -Dtransitive=false
```

I ended up with a `.m2` folder (originally empty) full of dependencies:

```
$ls
asm                       commons-cli          commons-logging    oro
backport-util-concurrent  commons-collections  commons-validator  xml-apis
classworlds               commons-digester     junit
com                       commons-io           log4j
commons-beanutils         commons-lang         org
```

It is supposed that only `aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.901.jar` should be downloaded.

Did I misunderstand something? I'm not familiar with Java language...

With or without flag `-Dtransitive=false` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The artifact has (really) no dependencies! ..but you do not consider the "dependency-plugin", you use.

Comment: ..and this plugin's dependencies Look very like your listing (+some trans): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/3.3.0

Comment: @xerx593 How can we exclude or filter out those (unrelated) "dependency-plugin" dependencies? The `AWS SDK For Java Bundle » 1.11.901` is just an example. Some other libraries have a few dependencies, and its dependencies could have a few others. I would like to download the target library as well as their dependencies plus dependencies of dependencies... In theory, I could run the target library (if runnable) without Internet access.